# Solution of differential equation in terms of incomplete gamma function

Tags: differential-equations, special-functions

I need help in solving equation 15 and 16 either manually or in *Mathematica* to get the solution in terms of the incomplete gamma function.
[image]

This is what *Mathematica* tells me. I can't understand what is the problem.
[image]

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE.  From experience I know that you are more likely to receive an answer if you demonstrate effort to solve this on your own, or request help with a specific method or idea.  Questions that look like "do my homework for me" are usually ignored.

Comment: Actually i tried  on mathematica and also manually but got stuck..just want to have hints how to proceed

Comment: I suggest you include what you tried.  Understand I am not personally demanding this (actually I think showing failed attempts is not really desirable; see [this](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1307/121)), I am merely trying to help you get answers, and I know that many people will not answer unless effort it demonstrated, for better or worse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
DSolve[e t''[e] + (1 - Pr/b^2 (1 + bs) + e) t'[e] == 0 &&  t[Pr/b^2] == 1 && t[0] == 0, t, e] 
                                                               // TraditionalForm // TeXForm
```

$$\left\{\left\{t\to \left(\{e\}\to \frac{\Gamma \left(\frac{(\text{bs}+1) \Pr
   }{b^2},0\right)-\Gamma \left(\frac{(\text{bs}+1) \Pr }{b^2},e\right)}{\Gamma
   \left(\frac{(\text{bs}+1) \Pr }{b^2},0\right)-\Gamma \left(\frac{(\text{bs}+1) \Pr
   }{b^2},\frac{\Pr }{b^2}\right)}\right)\right\}\right\}$$

Comment: Any idea "what is the problem" with the OP's code?

Comment: @MichaelE2 Which code ? :D. That's why I'm a strong believer in the need of the OP posting _some_ code. You can't teach anything in situations like this one: just see and look how it's done

Comment: I agree about posting code.  But since you retyped it, I thought you probably saw that there's no space between the ε and the θ in the picture of the OP's code.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Nope, my sight and patience aren't up to the task